# how to login with username in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hi this is my users model structure,

```
'name' => 'required|max:255',
'phone' => 'required|numeric',
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

And this is Profile model structure

```
'username' => 'required|max:255',
'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
```

I need keep up on this structure and login with username and password , because some users can not have login and cant take user and password .

I change Auth to this

```
public function create(array $data)
{
     $user = User::create([
         'email' => $data['email'],
         'phone' => $data['phone'],
     ]);
     $user->profile()->create(['name' => $data['name'],'password' =>bcrypt($data['password'])]);
     return $user;
}
```

and now how can i do login :| ?
I know need to change login method on this file     `laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\A‌​uth\AuthenticatesUse‌​rs.php`
 But i don't know what's the changes

Comment: You need to overwrite the register method...if you don't know how i can help you, but later...now i'm on my way to work!

Comment: @lewis4u I can wait for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to login right after registering, just do this:

```
Auth::attempt($data['name'], $data['password']);
```

If you're just want to login users, you could override `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard@attempt` method, but you could just use [`Auth::login`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

```
if ($request->login == $loginFromDB && Hash::check($request->password, $passwordFromDB)) {
    Auth::login($user, true); // User must be an User model instance
}
```

Comment: I know need to change login method on this file 
     `laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

But i don't know what's the changes

Comment: I cant undrestand my username is on profile table , this code how can detect check password on profile table /?

Comment: Just get the user with something like `$user = User::where('login', $request->login)->first()` and then get the hashed password with something like `$password = $user->profile()->password`

Comment: Its ok , And How Can I Login Just With Profile Username And Pass ? its impossible ?

Comment: You can use any credentials you want. Just do the check first and if credentials are ok, do `Auth::login`

Answer (score 0):

As for `create` method it looks like you need change `name` to `username` like `$user->profile()->create(['username' => ...`

For login, I think, you can using something like

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $profile = Profile::where('username', $request->get('username'))->first();

    if(!$profile)
    {
        // Username doesn't exist 
        // return error
    }

    if (Hash::check($request->get('password'), $profile->password))
    {
        // The passwords match, login by ID
        Auth::loginUsingId($profile->user_id);
        // return success
    }

    // return error (invalid password)
}
```

Comment: Its ok but some users Should not have username and password, and i take their user pass ... i cant change username .